# Induction cooktop tripping breaker (the IGBT was just repaced)

Tags: igbt, circuit-breaker, induction-heater

I have replaced the burned IGBT + added a new thermal paste, and it worked fine for about 10 minutes on the lower power setting, but when I turned it up to max it failed after a few seconds. I haven't opened it after the second failure yet, but I suspect the IGBT again. BTW the fan runs fine. Do you have any idea why the IGBT keeps failing? What else should I check/replace?

Comment: Hello Tomáš, what is the device name or number of your inductive cooking plate? The part name of the old and the new IGBT.

Comment: Could be all sorts of things. Check some voltages, or better yet get an oscilloscope and check for oscillations. Busted/dried electrolytic caps?

Answer (score 2):

It’s unlikely that the IGBT failed in the first place by itself. Unless you diagnosed what caused it and fixed that too, your problem will remain.

Moreover, a failed IGBT often takes gate drive circuitry with it in the fall when it fails.

You need to break out your oscilloscope and test to find the root cause. Any resonant tank capacitors being open circuit?